# Different activities on button click of different list view items

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I have an app containing a listview. When the listview item is clicked it opens up a new activity containing a textview and a Burton.

[Here](https://goo.gl/photos/ieLQQKNqJG5Sr5EF8) are the images of my listview.

Now if I press the button inside the activity of listview item 1 I want it to open activity 1, if I press the button inside the activity of listview item 2 I want it to open activity 2 and so on for "n" button clicks I want "n" activities to open. Is this possible?

**main activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "Country");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                                           R.layout.listview_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) country.get("name"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                          SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                    i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
                               .toString());
                    // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    }
    }
}
```

**singleitemview. Java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
TextView txtname;
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Get the name
    name = i.getStringExtra("name");

    // Locate the TextView in singleitemview.xml
    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    // Load the text into the TextView
    txtname.setText(name);

}
}
```

Comment: Okay.Where is your code ???

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I posted my code please have a look

Comment: do you want to open n instances of SingleItemView? or n different Activities like SingleItemView_1, ..., SingleItemView_n

Comment: n different activities like singleitemview

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked , according to that listView is set , and you want to open different activities on each item click as pre defined lik you said Activiy1 on first item and 2 on 2nd item click, so on.

you can do it with listView.setOnItemClickListener.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewXML_ID);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity1.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                break;


            }
        }
    });
```

And forget to declare those Activities in Manifest file.

```
 <activity android:name="packageName.Class1"></activity>
 <activity android:name="packageName.Class2"></activity>
```

Code for Activity1:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity1extends Activity{

Button btnActivity1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnActivity1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID_in_XML);//make a button in activity_main and assign it an id like i did here.
    btnActivity1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Class2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

In this way you can open Activities from an activity opened from a click of a List...

Comment: It's not when the list item I clicked. After the liistview item is clicked a opened the opened activity contains a button. That button click should open a new activity. And each liistview item after opened contains a button which should open different activities. Hope you on. Please help me

Comment: Buddy it is simple, add a button in Activity1 and Activity2 and as many activities you want then from those Actvities do coding on button to open another Activity..!

Comment: But the activity where I want to add the button is the activity which opens when clicked on the listview item . So literally I can only define only one button in the XML . so please help me buddy !

Comment: bro, so what's the matter, it is easy, i have posted all code up there, make listview put onitemCLickListener on it open different activity from from that list then in those activities make a button  then in the onClickListener of that button   open another activity.! why u r getting confused and making me too :p :D